# Error when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I get an issue when using wkhtmltopdf, I just installed the 64bits version and the nodejs dependency but I get an error :

My code :

```js
var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');

wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/out.pdf'));
```

My error :

```js
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)

npm ERR! GestionDettes@1.2.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the *******@1.2.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the GestionDettes package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls GestionDettes
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\*******
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\xampp\htdocs\********\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Do you have the binary installed/available?

Comment: Not on the command line, but I installed the 64bits version, how to activate the binary on the command line?

Comment: You need to add it to your PATH or change `wkhtmltopdf.command` to the path of the binary.

Comment: I'd like to add it to my PATH but I dont know the right path of wkhtmltopdf... C:/Users/username/ and?

Comment: The default install path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: I added `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe` to my PATH but it doesn't work too...

Answer (score 6):

Ensure wkhtmltopdf command line tool is installed. You can download it from: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

Then ensure the `bin` folder is on your PATH. `C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin` is the default installation path. Verify that it is correct for your machine.

Answer (score 1):

adding `spawnOptions` option worked for me

```js
wkhtmltopdf('http://google.com/', { pageSize: 'letter' spawnOptions:{shell: true}}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/out.pdf'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution here: https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf/issues/29

You need to set the absolute path for installed wkhtmltopdf.exe to wkhtmltopdf.command before using it, like this:

```
wkhtmltopdf.command = "C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe";
```

And install CLI from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html as it was mentioned in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

As we are using Js Report with Docker container so we were facing issue of Spawn error wkhtmltopdf.exe execution while rendering pdf in Windows 10 System.

How We solved:-
**in package,json we added "wkhtmltopdf-installer" package explicitly so it's updated wkhtmltopdf.exe as 64bit.**

{"wkhtmltopdf-installer": "~0.3.2"}